# Where to declare JDO Singleton PersistenceManagerFactory with multiple services

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo

I am working with GWT and have 4 Service Implementations that need a PersistenceManagerFactory.  I followed Google's advice on creating a singleton class, however I am unsure of where this class should be instantiated and referenced from in the server-side code.

The class looks like this

```
import javax.jdo.JDOHelper;
import javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactory;

public final class PMF {
    private static final PersistenceManagerFactory pmfInstance =
        JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory("transactions-optional");

    private PMF() {}

    public static PersistenceManagerFactory get() {
        return pmfInstance;
    }
}
```

But doing something like this in each Service Implementation seems to end up creating a unique copy of the singleton based on the error message I get "Application code attempted to create a PersistenceManagerFactory named transactions-optional, but one with this name already exists!"

```
@Override
 public void addCategory(Category category) {
  PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
  try {
        pm.makePersistent(category);
  } finally {
       pm.close();
     }
 }
```

So basically the first ServiceImpl that calls addCategory is fine, all others fail with the error above.  I am missing something vital here, I thought the whole point of the singleton class is to create a static PersistenceManagerFactory.  Any insights into what I am missing are greatly appreciated.

Comment: there must be something else going on. your PMF class looks correct.

Comment: do you have multiple copies of you PMF class? is it an internal class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PMF class should be a top level class, not an internal class.

Usually its `site.server.PMF`.

Comment: @Zach I'm curious. Was that what your problem was, or did that just help you figure something else out?

Comment: In general, I was confused about how singletons are used, how they become instantiated etc.  Your post helped me make sense of the singleton ecosystem.